# PHP get_declared_classes() of another project

Tags: php, php-7

Let's say you have two different PHP projects/applications (A and B). When [`get_declared_classes()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-declared-classes.php) is called in project A, it will return declared classes in project A, which is expected.

I'd like to get all declared classes in project B by running [a    command of] project A.

The most promising option which I've tried so far is to implement a file crawler in project A and run it on project B (recursive file iterator with a [tokenizer](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php) that extracts fully qualified names), but it's too slow.

Is there any way I can point `get_declared_classes()` written in project A to load project B's files? Is there some other default function which can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a autoloader to look also to the project B folder, or you can use set_include_path() to look also to project B. But in general I think iot is not best practice to do that. It will have also an performance impact when php need to search on both projects

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. There might be something I can brainstorm out of this idea... I'll look into it (if no other more elegant solution pops up).